# Why is this button requiring 2 clicks to revert state in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I want to click back and forth between pressed and not pressed for a button. But when pressed, requires 2 clicks to revert back to not pressed.

```
const [priority, setPriority] = useState('');
var isPriority = 0;

function swapPriority() {
    if (isPriority === 0) {
        setPriority("btn__danger");
        isPriority = 1;
    } else {
        setPriority("");
        isPriority = 0;
    }
}

const template = {
 <button
      type="button"
      className={'btn ' + priority}
      onClick={swapPriority}
 >
}
```

Comment: `if (isPriority === 0)` will **never** be false. `isPriority` gets recreated each render. So setting it in `swapPriority` is useless. This is exactly what state is for.

Answer (score 2):

In your code basically when you click the first time you set priority to "btn_danger" and isPriority to 0. But **isPriority is a normal variable** so when the code re-renders, it again sets isPriority to 0 (**although you set it to 1 previously, since value of normal variable does not persists between renders**). Now when you click again, the if condition is true (since isPriority is 0) so it executes setPriority(). But since **there is no change in the value inside setPriority() so no re-render occurs** and the isPriority is set to 1. Again when you click the button, **since isPriority is now 1** it behaves as you expect. As **@M-Raw** suggested above this is not the right way to handle this thing. (But it is a great way to understand how react works nontheless.)

Answer (score 0):

you're defining `priority` and changing `isPriority`
the react way would be like this:

```
const [priority, setPriority] = useState(false);

function swapPriority() {
 setPriority(!priority);
}

const template = {
 <button
  type="button"
  className={priority ? 'btn btn__danger' : 'btn '}
  onClick={swapPriority}
 >{priority ? 'danger' : 'not-danger'}</button>
}
```

Comment: Or just: `onClick={(priority) => setPriority(!priority)}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this results in the button being stuck in pressed mode, with class="btn__danger". Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: @Ben are you flipping the priority value with `setPriority(!priority)` notice the ! is important, you can add text to the button and see if the value is changing correctly, i'll update my answer to include it

Comment: Thanks, it worked! For some reason when using the shortcut for defining the function inside onClick it didn't work?